# Can't Edit "Languages" Speech to Text on Node-Red

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, node-red

When I add the "Speech to Text",can't edit "Languages"(I'd like to select "Japanese").Watch the ScreenShot(Change from 1 to 2).

[image: Display "languages" select]

[image: Don't display "languages" select]

Please help me.

Comment: This looks like a bug, I would raise a defect on github here https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-node-watson/issues

Comment: Thank your comment. Now, I ask the staff in IBM Japan wheter or not. I'd wait for his reply.

Answer (score 0):

The language list is populated dynamically after an API call. 
If this call fails (and therefore the list cannot be retrieved), the list will not show.

I was not able to reproduce the problem on my side, can you try again now? The service might have been down for a short moment.

Comment: mmm,I just use Node-Red on Bluemix...I'll give it another try.